# Calling a method belonging to object #1 from a function outside of object#1?

Tags: javascript, html

```
(function($){
    $.fn.kwicks = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            isVertical: false,
            sticky: false,
            defaultKwick: 0,
            event: 'mouseover',
            spacing: 0,
            duration: 500,
        };
        var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var WoH = (o.isVertical ? 'height' : 'width'); // WoH = Width or Height
        var LoT = (o.isVertical ? 'top' : 'left'); // LoT = Left or Top

        return this.each(function() {
            var container = $(this);

    ...

    yadda yadda yadda

    ...

                container.bind("mouseleave", function() {

                ...

                });
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

I want to call this "mouseleave" method onload.  How can I accomplish that?

If I can't accomplish it because it is a private method, how can I make it public?

Thanks in advance.  And yeah, I'm not going to be writing a book about how to code in javascript anytime soon... lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`container` is whatever you're calling `.kwicks()` on, so on that same element just trigger the `mouseleave` event, for example:

```
$(".whateverContainerIs").mouseleave();
//or
$(".whateverContainerIs").trigger("mouseleave");
//or
$(".whateverContainerIs").triggerHandler("mouseleave");
```

[`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) is a shortcut for [`.trigger("mouseleave")`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), then there's [`.triggerHandler("mouseleave")`](http://api.jquery.com/triggerHandler/) which just runs your handler, but the event doesn't bubble...if that matters (in most cases it doesn't, unless there's a `mouseleave` handler on a parent you don't want to fire).

Comment: I edited the code to try to show what container is.  There's a bunch of nesting, and I have no idea what is nested inside of what.  It's someone else's code that I've changed quite a bit, and it's working great, but I'm stumped on this part.  :(  From what I've gathered, $("blah") is the same as document.getElementById("blah"), but I have no idea how he could do $(this) if that was the case because "this" is an object, not a string.

Comment: @Michael - `$(this)` is a jQuery object wrapping a DOM element, you can still use the same selector to find the same DOM element and trigger the event, for example `$("#blah").mouseleave();`, does that make sense?

Comment: "does that make sense?"   Seeing as how I first started learning javascript about 5 days ago, no... it doesn't make sense... I'm in way over my head.  lol.

Comment: Oh, and FWIW, the id of "this" if I do alert(this.id) is "mainnavmenu", which is what I expected it to be, but document.getElementById('mainnavmenu').mouseleave(); does not work, nor do any of the other things that I've tried.  I've also used "for(var p in obj){ alert(p);}" to look at the components of mainnavmenu and other objects, and I've never seen "mouseleave" in the lists, unfortunately.

Comment: @Michael - `.mouseleave()` is a jQuery object method, you need `$('#mainnavmenu').mouseleave()`

Comment: Sadly, that does not work.  "var hmmm=$('#mainnavmenu');" ..... "for(var p in hmmm){  myfunclist+=p + ", ";}" ..... "window.clipboardData.setData("Text", myfunclist);</code>" yeilds the following: kwicks, outerWidth, innerWidth, outerHeight, innerHeight, scrollTop, scrollLeft, offsetParent, position, offset, dequeue, stop, queue, animate, fadeTo, fadeOut, fadeIn, slideToggle, slideUp, slideDown, _toggle, hide, show, ajaxSend, ajaxSuccess, ajaxError, ajaxComplete, ajaxStop, ajaxStart, serializeArray, serialize, _load, error, keyup, keypress, keydown, submit, select, change, mouseout, mouseover,

Comment: mousemove, mouseup, mousedown, dblclick, click, unload, scroll, resize, load, focus, blur, ready, hover, toggle, triggerHandler, trigger, unbind, one, bind, width, height, empty, remove, toggleClass, removeClass, addClass, removeAttr, replaceAll, insertAfter, insertBefore, prependTo, appendTo, contents, children, siblings, prevAll, nextAll, prev, next, parents, parent, extend, domManip, removeData, data, andSelf, map, slice, eq, replaceWith, html, val, hasClass, is, add, not, filter, clone, find, end, after, before, prepend, append, wrap, wrapInner, wrapAll, text, css, attr, index, each,

Comment: setArray, pushStack, get, size, jquery, init, 0, length, 

 
No "mouseleave".   :(

Comment: Thanks for trying, though.  I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I'll just have to code a work-around.  So long as the job gets done, I'm happy... OOP or not... who needs member functions anyways!